# NHibernate .SelectList() with List<string> in C#

Tags: c#, sql, linq, nhibernate

I have a database request which looks as follows:

```
var userHasProfessions = xy.GetUserProfessions();

var users = sessionService.GetDefaultSession()
    .Query<User>()
    .Where(a => userProfessions.Contains(a.Profession.Id))
    .ToList();
```

It gets all users that the requesting user is allowed to see, depending on his own profession. Now I wanna restrict that a little more, that he can only see some attributes of the users. Let's say for example:

```
id        -> yes
firstname -> yes
lastname  -> yes
address   -> no!
```

Now I tried t change the query to something like:

```
var userHasProfessions = xy.GetUserProfessions();

var users = sessionService.GetDefaultSession()
    .QueryOver<User>()
    .SelectList(list => list
      .Select(a => a.id)
      .Select(a => a.firstname)
      .Select(a => a.lastname))
    .Where(a => userProfessions.Contains(a.Profession.Id))
    .ToList();
```

Now my question... Is there a way to, for example, make a new List with these attributes and then loop through it? Something like that:

```
List<string> attributes = new List<string>(){"id", "firstname", "lastname"}

var userHasProfessions = xy.GetUserProfessions();

var users = sessionService.GetDefaultSession()
    .QueryOver<User>()
    .SelectList(
      //loop through attributes
    )
    .Where(a => userProfessions.Contains(a.Profession.Id))
    .ToList();
```

Thanks in advance :-)

**EDIT**

To make my question a little bit more clear. I wanna have the attributes that the user is allowed to see, dynmically changeable from a `List<string>` outside the query.

How can a achieve that?

Comment: I don't know anything about NHibernate, but can't you do `sessionService.GetDefaultSession().QueryOver<User>().Select(u => new { u.id, u.firstname, u.lastname})`?

Comment: @DavidG Thanks!, your solution would work, but only if a hardcode the attributes in the query. I want to have them into a separate list.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're asking here. Are you looking to dynamically query the columns?

Comment: @DavidG Exactly, I wanna have a List of the attibutes the user should see. This List is variable. That means the query should dynamically change the attributes allowed.

Comment: Then you're looking to use Dynamic Linq which I would strongly discourage. There's almost never a need to change the columns you require.

Comment: @DavidG Can you give me a useful example to do this with dynamic LINQ? Maybe as an answer so I could approve it.

Comment: Not really no. The problem is that even anonymous types are creates at compile time. There's some hacky solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000753/how-can-i-create-a-dynamic-multi-property-select-on-an-ienumerablet-at-runtime) but like I said above, are you really sure you need this?

Comment: @DavidG Actually I need it, because I have to display different attributes to users in different roles...

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
.Where(a => userProfessions.Contains(a.Profession.Id))
.Select(c => new User {
    id = c.id,
    firstname = c.firstname,
    lastname = c.lastname,
    address   c.address
}).ToList();
```

I am assuming list is type of `User`. Other wise you could use anonymous return i.d. `c => new { id="id",... }`

Comment: No List is type of string. My intention is to have the List externally in an variable, so I don't have to hardcode them in the query. Any other idea?

Comment: @RaphaelMüller, what is your expected output

Comment: I expect a user model that would look in JSON like `[{"id":1,"firstname":"Paul","lastname":"Paulsen","address":null}]` or without the address, that's not that important.

Comment: @RaphaelMüller, `.Select(u => new { u.id, u.firstname, u.lastname})` would work in that case