# How to reassign DataSource of ObjectDataSource after sorting?

Tags: .net, linq, objectdatasource

I have a Gridview that has an ObjectDataSource bound and I am doing sorting on the columns. In the `Sorting` event I call the following:

```
e.Cancel = True
Me.ods.Select()
Me.gv.DataBind()
```

All is fine. Now in the `ODS_Selected` event, I manipulate the returned list collection using a LINQ `OrderBy` statement. The problem is the `OrderBy` statement does *not* modify the elements directly in the collection and returns the result as an IEnumerable.

Still no big deal, I thought I could just take the result of the query (which has the items in the proper order) and reassign the referenced return collection (now a new variable) and be done. It does not work (ordering does work but not datasource manipulation) and nothing happens visually - no changes.

If I use a LINQ `Sort` this whole procedure works perfectly, because a `.Sort` manipulates the items in the collection directly. However I am using Reflection to reflect on the sort expression because children of Instance properties are used and bound and that makes sorting not so straight forward. Based on help from here ([How do I order a collection based on a child property using LINQ or a Lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023922/how-do-i-order-a-collection-based-on-a-child-property-using-linq-or-a-lambda)) I got all the sorting working so I can't use `.Sort` unless it's after the call to `.OrderBy`.

Here is the code from the ODS_Selected event:

```
Dim MyData As New List(Of MyCustomClass)
'Because objects are Reference types, setting RequestQueueData = e.ReturnValue means they will share the same memory address and any modifications to 'MyData will be reflected in 'e'.
MyData = e.ReturnValue
Dim query As IEnumerable(Of MyCustomClass) = MyData.OrderBy(blah,blah)
```

I have tried the following and none of them have worked:

```
MyData = query
```

...and tried:

```
MyData = query.ToList()
```

..and tried:

```
MyData.Clear()
MyData.AddRange(query)
```

The last one clears the collection and the .AddRange does not load anything back in: Count = 0, even though there are 9 results in the `query` results.

Any ideas on how to manipulate that reference type `MyData` to load it up or reassign it with the results that have been ordered?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Tried this as well and nothing happens to the bound Gridview's data. The collection after reassignment is *perfect* but nothing happens. Only when I use a `.Sort` on the collection for testing non-child instance properties does it work as I want. .`OrderBy' just is not permanently modifying that collection even though after reassignment it looks perfect:

```
Dim MyData2 As New List(Of MyCustomClass )
If query IsNot Nothing Then
 For Each mc As MyCustomClass In query.ToList()
   MyData2 .Add(req)
 Next
End If

MyData = New List(Of BLL.Entities.Request)
'After this point, MyData & MyData2 are in the proper order.
MyData  = MyData2
```

Comment: Problem may be your custom class. You may need to be using a DataView. You can check it out here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.aspx

EDIT
Telling us more about "MyCustomClass" may allow others to help you out more. We don't really know what your custom class is.

Comment: No I think you missed the whole deal here. List(Of T) will bind perfectly fine. Have been doing it for years and actually better than DataView IMO because it is strongly typed and 50 other reasons. I manipulate my collection with the .OrderBy and just need to figure out how to manipualte underlying datasource with the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this *does* work. Reassinging a *new* variable and then adding it back in does the trick and accomplishes what I want to do:

```
If query IsNot Nothing Then
   Dim queryTemp = query.ToList()
   MyData.RemoveRange(0, MyData.Count)
   MyData.AddRange(queryTemp)
End If
```

In my case, since ordering was done directly on the `MyData` object, I needed to place results in a new variable because once `RemoveRange` is called, both `query` and `MyData` will be empty. Then I add the sorted/ordered items back into the collection. Again, `MyData` is a reference to underlying datasource being bound.

This stemmed from the fact that`.OrderBy` does NOT change the actual element order - it is just reading the items of the collection in a particular order without changing the locations of the items in the collection. `.Sort` will actually sort the collection – thereby changing the locations of the items in the collection. However I couldn't use `.Sort` because of the specialized needs returned by the `.OrderBy` from a custom method call to break down an instance property sort expression (i.e. `ParentObject.FullName` as opposed to the simple solution where the sort expression is just `FullName` as all the examples provide)